# Proper indentation in javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm fairly new to coding what are some good rules of thumb to make my code easy to read to me and others. When do I indent where should my curly braces be? If you have any resources for websites that are good tutorials for this please link me. I've finished codeacademy and a lot of other starter resources for js. I still seem to be struggling to figure out how to make my code look pretty and readable. Thanks for everybody's help and suggestions in advance!

Comment: Who closed? Many languages have official coding standards now. Saying that Javascript doesn't would be a perfectly valid answer as well as specifying the most common guidelines...

Answer (score 5):

Here you go: And like TGH says, there is no "right way", only the way you and your collegues agree on. As long as its consistent and you all agree, have at it.

this will help with prettying up your code:
http://jsbeautifier.org/

the following will help you with some standards.

https://github.com/v0lkan/o2.js/blob/master/CONVENTIONS.md

https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js/

http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/

http://addyosmani.com/blog/javascript-style-guides-and-beautifiers/

Comment: +1 for jsbeautifier.org - a great resource for prettying up your code.

Answer (score 2):

Coding style is generally decided on per-project. For example:

- jQuery [uses tabs](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#spacing)
- Bootstrap [uses 2 spaces, no semicolons](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#js)

The one caveat is with [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://es5.github.io/#x7.9), primarily regarding a few "*restricted productions*" which do not allow line-breaks.

```
return            // returns `undefined`
{                 // becomes a block rather than an `Object`
    key: "value"  // and a label rather than a property
};
```

Though, this brace style is safe in most other cases:

```
function foo(bar)
{
    console.log(foo, bar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no special rules for JavaScript since it's not a white space sensitive language. It comes down to your own personal preference, so there is really no right or wrong. 
Just pick one convention and use it consistently.